# Is there a event handler for new comments for Facebook comment plug in?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to leverage Facebook comments plug in and push notifications for post on my page. What I am basically trying to do is:

1. user creates a post
2. the Facebook comment is dynamically inserted for that post by suffixing id from that post.

The above two are already done in the page.

Now what I want is, when someone posts, a push notification is subscribed if the user allows and when a comment is made a push notification is pushed to the user. The user is identified by the ID of the post as well which is stored on database.

I tried to attach a event handler on Facebook iframe comment box but was thrown with cross origin error.

I was trying webhooks but couldn't work on local host and found I need ngrok to validate my test url.  I am posting this to ask is that is my flow even valid or I am seriously misunderstanding the concept. If someone could validate my flow.I will be happy to work on it or I will be just wasting my time.

Here's the link with the Facebook comments applied on post:
https://helpingcow.com/postit/get_share_listings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facebook have killed "comment.create" event subscriptions.See the answer here to my related question [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54747479/5798692).The preferred method is to use webhooks.
As I have already mentioned in question,that I cant use ngrok because it only supports python 3.6 and above and I have 2.7.

But I used [localtunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) from npm.It did the work and I have validated my localhost url and test webhooks are now functional.I really dont need the data from the json payload from webhooks but just need a way to get to id of the posted item when the facebook comment is posted but there is no way the client can know about that event unless some server sent events are used.